# Evaluating $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm dx}$

Tags: integration

Attempting to calculate $\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm dx}$,
$$\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm dx}=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(y\tan\theta)^2+y^2}}y\sec^2\theta \mathrm d\theta}=\int{\sec\theta d\theta}=\ln(\sec\theta +\tan\theta)=\ln\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+1}+\frac{x}{y}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right),$$
where $x=y\tan\theta$

However [Wolfram Integrator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1/sqrt%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29&random=false) somehow returns
$$\ln\left(2\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right)$$
as the answer. Where did I go wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: For one, you should have factored out a $1/y$ rather than a $1/x$.  The factor of two can be wrapped up in an integration constant.

Comment: The only nitpick I have so far is that the coefficient in front of the natural logarithm at the end of your solution should be $\frac{1}{y}$ and not $1/x$.

Comment: I think the wolfram integrator is wrong see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29&dataset=

Comment: @Shobhit: It isn't wrong, it just chose a (seemingly arbitrary) specific constant of $\ln(2)$. The only thing I dislike is how both have absorbed the $-\ln(y)$ into the constant.

Comment: @Clayton agreed

Comment: Thi is a table integral in S. K. Stein, Calculus and analytic geometry, 4th ed. NY, St. L., A, B,.., McGraw-Hill, 1987.

Comment: In you know $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \operatorname{asinh}(x)+C$$then you can do this integral as $\operatorname{asinh}(x/y)+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** after you fix the mistake in the last step, differentiate the function $$x\mapsto \ln\left(\frac{1}{y}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right)-\ln\left(2\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right)$$ with respect to $x$. It's easy to do so in your head. Also do not forget that you should consider the absolute value appropriately ($\int \frac 1x\mathrm dx)=\ln (|x|)$) and to add an arbitrary constant when you integrate.

Comment: It's even easier if you expand the right-hand side to see how much cancellation there is and then differentiate :)

Comment: @Clayton That's exactly what I have in mind.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for stating what you already knew. I thought you were implying taking the derivative of the function as it looks was very easy, and I personally didn't want to do that.

Comment: @Clayton I'm glad for your comment. If it wasn't clear to you what I meant, it won't be for other people either.

Answer (score 2):

To find out the reason you only requires some basic knowledge of logarithms. In short, there is only a constant difference between these two logarithms.

Since we are integrating with respect to $x$, we regard $y$ as constant and therefore $\ln y$ is const. Let's add the constant term of indefinite integral:
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx & = \ln\left(\frac1y\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right)+C \\
& = \ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)-\ln y+C \\
& = \ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)+C_0 \\
& = \ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)+\ln 2+C' \\
& = \ln\left(2\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)\right)+C' \\
\end{align}
so the two answers are exactly the same.